# Image slide gallery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a website for a friend which includes some of his latest instagram posts within a slideshow. I have included left and right cursors for the user to slide from image to image, but I am having trouble achieving my end goal - when the user clicks on the right arrow, it will slide the images and continue regardless of how many times he clicks it. There are about 8 images to be included. The same should apply when I click on the left cursor.

The slider is not responding as it should. Based on the current code, when I click on the right arrow, it brings up the next image until it reaches the last one. Then I click on the right arrow twice, the first time nothing happens, the second time it loops back and brings up the second image in the array, not the first

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".disciplines img").hover(function(){ 
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
  });

  $(".disciplines").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).find('h3').slideDown();
  });

  $(".disciplines").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('h3').slideUp();
  });

  var sliderImages = [];
  var counter = 0;

  sliderImages[0] = "images/i1.png";
  sliderImages[1] = "images/i2.png";
  sliderImages[2] = "images/i3.png";

  $("#right-arrow").click(function(){
    counter++;
    $(".active").attr("src", sliderImages[counter]);

    if (counter > sliderImages.length)
    {
      counter = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="instagram-feed">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>INSTAGRAM GALLERY</h2>
    <div class="insta-gallery">
      <img src="images/left-arrow.png" class="arrow" id="left-arrow">
      <img src="images/i1.png" class="active">  
      <img src="images/right-arrow.png" class="arrow" id="right-arrow">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: So... what is your question exactly?

Comment: the slider is not responding as it should. Based on the current code, when I click on the right arrow, it brings up the next image until it reaches the last one. Then I click on the right arrow twice, the first time nothing happens, the second time it loops back and brings up the second image in the array, not the first.

Comment: Please remember to update the question with any relevant details. People won't necessarily read though comments for updates.

Comment: Well if you add a snippet the  code you've added triggers an error, so you've not copied the code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that your comparison is `greater than or equal to` using `>=` instead of just a `greater than`  (`>`).

Your counter was going higher than 3 because it didn't count `3` as a reason to reset the counter (*since your code says counter must be `greater than` the length, which is 3*). This is why it carried on instead of resetting.

```js
var sliderImages = [];
var counter = 0;

sliderImages[0] = "http://placehold.it/100x100";
sliderImages[1] = "http://placehold.it/200x100";
sliderImages[2] = "http://placehold.it/300x100";

$("#right-arrow").click(function(){

$(".active").attr("src", sliderImages[counter]);
counter++;
$('#count').text(counter);
if (counter >= sliderImages.length)
  {
    counter = 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="instagram-feed">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>INSTAGRAM GALLERY</h2>
    <div class="insta-gallery">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" class="arrow" id="left-arrow">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="active">  
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" class="arrow" id="right-arrow">
    </div>
    <p id="count">0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ProEvilz! You have saved my day :)

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding!